# Image recognition for dog types not working, my models might be the issue but am new to it

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

I came across this dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/stanford-dogs-dataset

Wanted to try experimenting with machine learning by my own as I tried following guides on youtube. Have no idea on how models should be built. I get the basic in terms of the neurons and layers but not sure why the accuracy and the loss feels wrong. Any guidelines/explanation for model creations(Activation,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D, Flatten,loss,optimizer)

I've tried changing the activation and loss as a trial and error to grasp the concept.

## i think my issues are these

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=["accuracy"])
```

My Jupyter Notebook File:
[My Jupyter Notebook File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hY5hZeYaf4yV4nGGIXbGjjHvij-S9X3w)

[Accuracy and Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRo8h.png)
As you can see the accuracy is garbage and the loss is off the charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Classifying images of dogs into various categories is a Classification task**. There are two types of problems in Machine Learning: [Classification and Regression](https://medium.com/quick-code/regression-versus-classification-machine-learning-whats-the-difference-345c56dd15f7).

Classification deals with categorical labels and therefore requires a suitable loss function. You should use the `categorical_crossentropy` loss function like:

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=["accuracy"])
```

See [here](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html#cross-entropy) for more information.

[Mean Squared Error ( MSE )](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html#mse-l2) is used for regression problems as it deals with continuous labels. It is used to find the best-fit line for a particular dataset so that the MSE is the least.

I think this should solve your problem. **If the problem still persists, then try these steps:**

1. Lower the learning rate to 0.0001 or even smaller.
2. Use `Dropout` layers.
3. Use `LeakyReLU` layers.

Comment: I've replace the loss="binary_crossentropy" with "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", added a learning rate while tweak the value, changed from relu to LeakyReLU but my accuracy and loss is still pretty bad. Am not sure which part of my model is wrong as currently am just experimenting.